# perl accessing multidimensional arrays

Tags: perl

I'm using the Perl `TMDB` module

How would I get the elements in the example from the code below so

`my $width = '1000'` and `my $file_path = "/yDIVWFJqFLIeS8E1R6GG9uwPMS3.jpg"`

```
my @images = $movie->images;

# print " <p>backdrops </p>";
print OUT JSON::to_json(\@images) ; ## Dump.txt below

foreach my $image (@images) {
   #print $movie->cast;
   my $backdrops = $image->{backdrops};
   my $posters = $image->{posters};      
   #print " <p>backdrops" . JSON::to_json(\@backdrops) . "</p>";

     foreach my $backdrop ($image{backdrops}) {
         my $width = $backdrop->{width};
         my $file_path= $backdrop->{file_path};
         print " <p>backdrops </p>";
         print "<div>width : $width <br />$file_path : $file_path </div>";  
     }
}
```

Sample of Dump.txt

```
[{
  "posters":
    [{"vote_average":5.89446589446589,"aspect_ratio":0.67,"width":1000,"file_path":"/yDIVWFJqFLIeS8E1R6GG9uwPMS3.jpg","vote_count":11,.....}],
  "id":60304,
  "backdrops":
    [{"vote_average":5.49206349206349,"aspect_ratio":1.78,"width":1920,"file_path":"/4wieJ74tXkZDMiiwJ6yMr7LgSpR.jpg","vote_count":11,.....}]
}]
```

Comment: The backdrop loop should be `$image->{backdrops}` not `$image{backdrops}`

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> foreach my $backdrop ($image{backdrops}) {
>   ... 
> }
> ```

There are two problems with this code. You would have found the first by including `use strict` in your code. That would have pointed out that you are trying to access a hash called `%image` where no such hash exists. You actually have a hash reference that is stored in a scalar variable called `$image`. So you need to access the values using the `->` syntax, not a direct hash look-up.

```
 foreach my $backdrop ($image->{backdrops}) {
   ... 
 }
```

Now we're getting to `$image->{backdrops}`, but what is in that value? You are treating it like a list or an array. But it's actually an array *reference*. So you need to de-reference  this reference in order to get back to the array. You do this using `@{ ...}`.

```
 foreach my $backdrop (@{ $image->{backdrops} }) {
   ... 
 }
```

That should work.

Comment: Thats what I love about perl every time I lern something new! Thanx @Dave Cross